# How can I easily INSERT data in a table from multiple columns from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I want to take all phone numbers from the companies table, and put that in a dedicated phone numbers table, is there an easy way to do this using (if possible) only one query?

example data from the companies table (tel3 and tel4 could have phone numbers):

| id | tel | tel2 | tel3 | tel4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32772373636 | 32724522341 |  |  |
| 2 | 32783675626 |  |  |  |
| 3 | 32968381949 |  |  |  |

expected example output in phonenrs table:

| id | company_id | phonenr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 32772373636 |
| 2 | 1 | 32724522341 |
| 3 | 2 | 32783675626 |
| 4 | 3 | 32968381949 |

Comment: not sure if the markdown is wrong? on the question creation page it was showing it correctly for me

Comment: i've fixed your markdown, just make sure to give extra space before table

Comment: Be careful when using UNION, as it does not support effective ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement from a query that `union all`s the phone numbers:

```sql
INSERT INTO numbers (company_id, phonenr)
SELECT it, tel FROM numbers WHERE tel IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT it, tel2 FROM numbers WHERE tel2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT it, tel3 FROM numbers WHERE tel3 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT it, tel4 FROM numbers WHERE tel4 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the **EXACT** match to your intended output, first we need to add a row id for your new `id` column. Then,to make sure the sorting precedence of tel > tel2 > tel3 > tel4, we can perform a trick to do so. Here is the code written and tested in workbench:

```
select @row_id:=@row_id+1 as id, id as company_id,trim(leading '0' from phone ) as phonenr
from
(select id,ifnull(concat('000',tel),1) as phone from companies
union all
select id,ifnull(concat('00',tel2),1) from companies
union all
select id,ifnull(concat('0',tel3),1) from companies
union all
select id,ifnull(tel4,1) from companies
) t1, 
(select @row_id:=0) t2
where phone !=1
order by company_id,phone
;
-- result:
# id, company_id, phonenr
1, 1, 32772373636
2, 1, 32724522341
3, 2, 32783675626
4, 3, 32968381949
```

As you can see, by adding different number of leading zero to the phone,we can manipulate the sorting precedence. Without it, I got 32724522341 instead of 32772373636 for the first line.